# Ruby on rails: Calendar with events

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, calendar, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I want to create a default calendar which can be displayed by month. The calendar by default has scheduled yearly events included in it. I will display this calendar in every user's profile. Now the user can look at the events on the calendar and the user should have the ability to mark the event as attending or not attending by just clicking on the event in the calendar. Are there any gems or plugins that can help

so far i found:

https://github.com/elevation/event_calendar

https://github.com/topfunky/calendar_helper

Comment: Re-tagged from fullcalendar to calendar. Fullcalendar is a jquery plugin, which might be able to help you, but not specifically in the question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I used Full calender. It is what i was looking for.

https://github.com/bokmann/fullcalendar-rails